# Arrow to point particular location in iPad

Tags: ios, ipad, cllocationmanager

I have to point the arrow to particular location based on the current location. For that I am using `didUpdateHeading` delegate method for getting the true heading value.

In iPhone( Portrait mode) the arrow image is showing perfectly. But in iPad its not showing correctly. It is in Landscape mode.

The code I am using to find the bearing distance is,

```
- (void)UpdateCompass:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    CLLocation *newLocation = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:m_nLatitude  longitude:m_nLongitude];
    CLLocation* target = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:questionLatitude  longitude:questionLangitude ];
    _latestBearing = [self getHeadingForDirectionFromCoordinate:newLocation.coordinate toCoordinate:target.coordinate];
    CGFloat degrees = _latestBearing - m_CLHeading.magneticHeading;
    CGAffineTransform cgaRotate = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation([self degreesToRadians:degrees]);
    m_arrowImage.transform = cgaRotate;
}

- (double)degreesToRadians:(double)degrees
{
    return degrees * M_PI / 180.0;
}

- (double)radiansToDegrees:(double)radians
{
    return radians * 180.0/M_PI;
}

- (double)getHeadingForDirectionFromCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)fromLoc toCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)toLoc
{
    double lat1 = [self degreesToRadians:fromLoc.latitude];
    double lon1 = [self degreesToRadians:fromLoc.longitude];
    double lat2 = [self degreesToRadians:toLoc.latitude];
    double lon2 = [self degreesToRadians:toLoc.longitude];
    double dLon = lon2 - lon1;
    double y = sin(dLon) * cos(lat2);
    double x = cos(lat1) * sin(lat2) - sin(lat1) * cos(lat2) * cos(dLon);
    double radiansBearing = atan2(y, x);

    if(radiansBearing < 0.0)
        radiansBearing += 2*M_PI;
        return  [self radiansToDegrees:radiansBearing];
}
```

How can I make this work for iPad?

Answer (score 0):

Check whether device is ipad or iphone and write your code accordingly

```
if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
{
     // The device is an iPad running iPhone 3.2 or later.
}
else
{
     // The device is an iPhone or iPod touch.
}
```

Comment: That I can do. But the above code is not working in iPad. i am looking for a code which is working in iPad also.

Comment: can you put any screen shot how it is showing differently in iPhone and iPad